# How to implement Autofac with mvc3 step by step

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I want to implementnt autofac repository with mvc3 application. Please let me know how to implement step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do in this case.

**1) I would let `NuGet` download and resolve all the dependencies for `AutoFac`. From the package manager console, execute**

```
PM> Install-Package Autofac
```

This should automatically reference `Autofac` and `Autofac.Integration.Mvc` in your project.

**2) Create `Bootstrapper.cs` in the application root with the following code**

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        SetAutofacContainer();
    }

    private static void SetAutofacContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Register all respository classes
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ReportRepository).Assembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }        
}
```

**3) Call `Bootstrapper's Run` method from Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Run();
}
```

Comment: I thought I read InstancePerHttpRequest is deprecated in favor of InstancePerRequest.

Comment: Good to know that @ErikNoren. Then in that case it will be replaced by `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 1) Download autofac dll from 
 https://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/list?can=1&q=
 For example : 
 https://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/detail?name=Autofac-3.0.0.0-NET40.zip&can=1&q=

 2) Add the reference of dll.

 3) Register SQL class in global.asax file.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterType<DataManagerMasterSQL>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: I would take a different approach on how to reference and resolve external assemblies and how to wire up the call to `Autofac`. Please refer my answer.